# Automatic Heap dump when reaches a certain threshold limit in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am looking for a automatic way of taking a heap dump in case of memory or cpu reaches a certain threshold limit.
`For Example : if ec2 machine reaches 80% of memory or cpu usage without instance going OOM we can get a automatic heap dump.`

We are trying to investigate an issue(which happened multiple times in past couple of months) for both prod/stage instances where ec2 machine without going OOM (remain within configured jvm memory)crashed and no heap dump was taken since we were taking heap dump based on jvm going OOM.

Also we were seeing memory getting increase in a matter of an hour but since it happened off hours we were not able to take the heap dump.

Comment: The easiest way would be to use `cron` and take a dump every 5-10 minutes. I'd also do a stack dump. If your app truly crashes, then the last dump should give you some insight. But if your app truly crashes, you'll get more insight from logging the exception that caused it to crash.

Comment: @kdgregory Cron every 5-10mins will be too overwhelming and exact for getting exact issue would be difficult.
- Logging at what part is the issue there is no one operation where it crashes it goes down any time also ec2 instance becomes unresponsive.

Comment: I am looking for more of the automation to put in place via running a aws lambda function or run a script which when identifies abnormality like high cpu/memory takes a heap/thread dump automatically and keeps in s3 bucket.

Comment: So let me see if I understand: your EC2 instance becomes unresponsive, but you want to use a Lambda to trigger a heap dump of a Java process on that instance? Good luck with that.

Comment: No before becoming unresponsive, once a threshold limit of memory let's say reaches at 70% from 30% that when we want a automation process to kick in and take a heap dump.